# Automatic conversion of evtx to plaintext logs

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a Windows Server 2008 running MicroSoft Exchange. The Audit Logs are stored in evtx and I am trying to export the logs to a 3rd party collector. The agents we have used (Snare Epilog, open source among them) do not recognized the evtx format and do not forward them to the collecting server.

I am attempting to implement a workaround via Powershell and Task Scheduler. The problem I am facing is that while I can access the evtx and save it as a .txt, I am reparsing the entire log every time. However, I would like to only send the new events every 5 minutes or less.

The code I am using is this:

```
$File = "C:\text.txt; Get-WinEvent -Path C:\test.evtx | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $File -append -width 750
```

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Get-EventLog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834.aspx), rather than [Get-WinEvent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849682.aspx), then use the After parameter to only get the last five minutes of events or better still keep track of the most recent event message you have seen.

Here's how to get the last five minutes of the Application log.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -After $((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great, save for just one issue. It does only grab the event from the 5 minute span,(which is perfect) however, it does append extra data that is not desirable. As this data is present in every output of the 5 minute query, I wonder if this is somehow filterable? I feel I am missing something simple. 

Not sure if etiquette allows the pasting of those logs here.

Comment: I cleared the logs, and that extra data is no longer being added to the log entries.